# optional route params, web api 2

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I trying to learn Web API 2 / MVC, and need a little assistance trying to set up a controller, which allows for optional params.

My controller method looks like:

```
[Route("{sender}/{displayLength}/{displayStart}")]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetSenderMessages(string sender, int? displayLength, int? displayStart)
        {
}
```

Now, either displayLenght, displayStart can be optional, these are going to be used to control paging in a mobile app.

If i send

> //server/route/wayne/1

then it complains about not matching the parameters.

What am i missing here guys?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this: [Optional URI Parameters and Default Values](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#optional)?